# Schema Generator cannot determine GraphQL output type for custom object within DTO

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, typegraphql

Coming from a laravel background I try to get into node.js/graphQL/MongoDB and stumbled over `nest.js` framework which looks pretty nice. So I tried to set up a simple GraphQL API for testing and understanding how it all works. Therefore I created a mongoose Schema for a user as well as a model (`type-graphql`) and a `DTO` for creating such a user via mutation.

This works pretty fine but then I wanted to add a nested object called settings within the user to try how this would work and I simply don't get it and also don't find any `nest.js` or `type-graphql` specific examples for such an implementation. Is this simply not feasible using the "code first" approach of `nest.js`? Because the schema generator always gives me an error while compilation saying :

> **"UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot determine GraphQL output type for settings".**

user.model.ts

```
import { Field, ID, ObjectType } from 'type-graphql'
import UserSettingsType from './user.settings.type'

@ObjectType()
export class User {
  @Field((type) => ID)
  id: string

  @Field()
  email: string

  @Field((type) => UserSettingsType)
  settings: {}
}
```

user.settings.type.ts

```
import { Field, ObjectType } from 'type-graphql'

@ObjectType()
export class UserSettings {
  @Field()
  theme: string

  @Field()
  description?: string

  @Field((type) => [String])
  visited: string[]
}
```

new-user.input.ts

```
import { IsOptional, IsEmail, IsBoolean, Length, MaxLength, IsArray } from 'class-validator'
import { Field, InputType } from 'type-graphql'
import UserSettingsType from '../graphql/user.settings.type'

@InputType()
export class NewUserInput {
  @Field()
  @IsEmail()
  email: string

  @Field((type) => UserSettingsType)
  @IsOptional()
  @IsArray()
  settings: {}
}
```

As you can see I defined a new type UserSettings in a separate file (following the best practices of `nest.js`) and allocated it as a type within the User model as well as the new-user DTO class. The error is thrown for the `DTO class` (NOT for the model) and if I change it there to something like [String] instead of UserSettingsType it is compiling.

I'm not sure if you need the resolver or the service/mongoose logic for this actual problem if so I can also post that of course!

Comment: Hi, have you managed to fix this problem? Could you share something? I have a similar problem when I try to make my input, with Array of string. Still don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Hi! Actually I stopped using nest.js after heading other problems as well and decided to use other technologies for my upcoming framework. So sorry I cannot help you with this.

Answer (score 19):

Had similar issue migrating from express to nestjs.

After reading the [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/resolvers#code-first) realised that problem isn't the nested objects, but wrong imports.

You should use `@nestjs/graphql` imports instead of `type-graphql`.

E.G.

```js
// changes this
import { Field, ID, ObjectType } from 'type-graphql'
// to
import { Field, ID, ObjectType } from '@nestjs/graphql'
```

Same applies to any other import from `type-graphql`

Comment: What if I'm only using express and type-graphql?

Comment: This solved a similar issue that I got when upgrading nestjs.

Comment: Same as @theva, had to replace all type-graphql by @nestjs/graphql, the schema.gql generated was from type-graphql

Comment: I would really like to know the answer if you are not using nestjs

Comment: happened to me when i forgot to add @ObjectType() to the entity object.